# Variables in another file won't display as an <li> in shopping cart page

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-cookies, shopping-cart

There are two main problems. First, I'm having trouble displaying the value of the item which should vary depending on the button selected. The innerHTML of the selected h3 element is supposed to enter into sessionStorage when activated from the source file. Then it's value goes to the receiving file as variable "ai" which will be appended as an li element into the unordered list of the page. The Second concern is the other function that the button in the source file performs. It's purpose is to alert that the item has been added to the shopping cart, but the function only displays in jsfiddle and not on glitch.com; where I'm creating the website. I believe it has something to do with the version of jquery the function uses or the source code. Any help on either of these is greatly appreciated.

Here is the source file...

Javascript/JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var button = "none";
        $(".button").click(function() {
            button = $(this).attr("data-name");
            alert(button);
        });
    });  
    function setWinHon() {
      var i = document.getElementById("WinHon").innerHTML;
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", i);
    }
    function setGolRod() {
      var i = document.getElementById("GolRod").innerHTML;
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", i);
    }
    function setMexPlu() {
      var i = document.getElementById("MexPlu").innerHTML;
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", i);
    }
    function setJasMin() {
      var i = document.getElementById("JasMin").innerHTML;
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", i);
    }
    function setCriTru() {
      var i = document.getElementById("CriTru").innerHTML;
      sessionStorage.setItem("item", i);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
</head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div id="text">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3 id="WinHon">Winter Honeysuckle $50</h3>        
            <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="align" align="left">
              <li>Height:</li>
              <li>Width:</li>
              <li>Maintenance:</li>
              <li>Environment:</li>
              <li>Nomenclature:</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="div1">Lonicera fragrantissima is a species of flowering plant in the honeysuckle family known by the common names winter honeysuckle, fragrant honeysuckle, January jasmine, Chinese honeysuckle, kiss-me-at-the-gate, and sweet breath of spring. 
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="setWinHon()" data-name="Winter Honeysuckle">Buy Now!</button></p>
          </div>
          <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9c36ac94-6707-41ee-a6b7-a39f46cd02e3%2FWinter%20Honeysuckle.jfif?1544561317954">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3 id="GolRod">Goldenrod $10</h3>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="align" align="left">
              <li>Height:</li>
              <li>Width:</li>
              <li>Maintenance:</li>
              <li>Environment:</li>
              <li>Nomenclature:</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="div1">Solidago, commonly called goldenrods, is a genus of about 100 to 120 species of flowering plants in the aster family, Asteraceae. Most are 
          herbaceous perennial species found in open areas such as meadows, prairies, and savannas.
        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="setGolRod()" data-name="Goldenrod">Buy Now!</button></p>
          </div>
          <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9c36ac94-6707-41ee-a6b7-a39f46cd02e3%2FGoldenrod.jpg?1544630990872">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3 id="MexPlu">Mexican Plum $30</h3>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="align" align="left">
              <li>Height:</li>
              <li>Width:</li>
              <li>Maintenance:</li>
              <li>Environment:</li>
              <li>Nomenclature:</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="div1">Prunus mexicana, commonly known as the Mexican plum, is a North American species of plum tree that can be found in the central United States and 
          Northern Mexico. Its native range stretches from Coahuila and San Luis Potosí north as far as Wisconsin and South Dakota, east to Georgia, 
          Kentucky, and Ohio.
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="setMexPlu()" data-name="Mexican Plum">Buy Now!</button></p>
          </div>
          <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9c36ac94-6707-41ee-a6b7-a39f46cd02e3%2FMexican%20Plum.jfif?1544631101080">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3 id="JasMin">Jasmine $20</h3>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="align" align="left">
              <li>Height:</li>
              <li>Width:</li>
              <li>Maintenance:</li>
              <li>Environment:</li>
              <li>Nomenclature:</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="div1">Jasmine is a genus of shrubs and vines in the olive family. It contains around 200 species native to tropical and warm temperate regions of 
            Eurasia, Australasia and Oceania. Jasmines are widely cultivated for the characteristic fragrance of their flowers.
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="setJasMin()" data-name="Jasmine">Buy Now!</button></p>
          </div>
          <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9c36ac94-6707-41ee-a6b7-a39f46cd02e3%2FJasmine.jpg?1544631121391">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3 id="CriTru">Crimson Trumpet $15</h3>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="align" align="left">
              <li>Height:</li>
              <li>Width:</li>
              <li>Maintenance:</li>
              <li>Environment:</li>
              <li>Nomenclature:</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="div1">Lonicera sempervirens is a species of honeysuckle native to the eastern United States. It can grow in many areas due to its hardiness. It is most
          often grown as a plant for wildlife. Ruby-throated hummingbirds use it in their natural range as well as other birds, butterflies, and bees.
            <button class="button" id="button5" type="button" onclick="setCriTru()" data-name="Crimson Trumpet">Buy Now!</button></p>
          </div>
          <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/9c36ac94-6707-41ee-a6b7-a39f46cd02e3%2FTrumpet%20Honeysuckle.jpg?1545705756174">
        </div>
      </div>  
    </center>  
  </body>
```

Here is the shopping cart (receiving file)...

```
<head>
    <script>
      function appendItems() {
          var ai = sessionStorage.getItem("item");
          ai = $("<li></li>").text("Text.");
          $("ul").append(ai);
          }
    </script>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <h1>Shopping list</h1>
      <p>So far you have ordered...</p>
    </div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="list">
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

The shopping cart should produce an li element containing the value called by whichever button is selected and the button selected should alert "plantname" & " has now been added to your shopping cart!". However, nothing currently happens when the button is clicked

Comment: Consider using `data` properties and a generic function that can use that data via jQuery rather than stamping out a function per entry here that's 99% the same as the others.

Comment: Also since you're using jQuery, use jQuery. Don't mess around with the core JavaScript methods like `document.getElementById("JasMin").innerHTML`, when instead you can do the much more concise `$('#JasMin').html()`